# Can't install MS true type fonts

Tags: software-installation, fonts

The `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is installed but no fonts in  `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts`. message in this folder reads:

```
License refused.

Please reinstall the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package (e.g. via apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer to get prompted for the license again.
```

Re-installing the installer proceeds until license. Unable to click OK at bottom.

When attempting to install `netflix-desktop` I have the same problem. Message reads

```
It appears you have not installed MS true type fonts. You need to accept the license agreement and install these fonts for Netflix Desktop to work properly.
```

I checked the accept box in the previous screen but still get this message.

Answer (score 3):

Use your <kbd>Tab</kbd>  key to select the OK option.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Tab -> Ok